# Moving Visual Studio tlog files

Tags: visual-studio, logging, directory

There are many *.tlog files generated by Visual Studio, and I'd like to ask you how can I move them to another directory. I've found only a way how to disable them using TrackFileAccess, but that's not what I want. Thanks.